# Add Coupon Percentage to Cart Page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, coupon

I'm trying to display the coupon percentage in the cart page, however I receive several errors.

This is my custom code:

```
// Add Coupon Percentage to Cart

function my_coupon_percentage_cart($value, $coupon)
{
    if($coupon->discount_type == 'percent' && !empty($coupon->coupon_amount))
    {
        $amt = "<br><br><p><em><strong>{$coupon->coupon_amount}% OFF</strong></em></p>";   
    }

    return $value.$amt;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html','my_coupon_percentage_cart',10,2);
```

These are the PHP errors:

```
[15-Sep-2022 13:55:13 UTC] discount_type was called incorrectly. Coupon properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_update_shipping_method'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::update_shipping_method, WC_AJAX::get_cart_totals, woocommerce_cart_totals, wc_get_template, include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php'), wc_cart_totals_coupon_html, apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, my_coupon_percentage_cart, WC_Legacy_Coupon->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[15-Sep-2022 13:55:13 UTC] coupon_amount was called incorrectly. Coupon properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_update_shipping_method'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::update_shipping_method, WC_AJAX::get_cart_totals, woocommerce_cart_totals, wc_get_template, include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php'), wc_cart_totals_coupon_html, apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, my_coupon_percentage_cart, WC_Legacy_Coupon->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
[15-Sep-2022 13:55:13 UTC] coupon_amount was called incorrectly. Coupon properties should not be accessed directly. Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'), do_action('template_redirect'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, do_action('wc_ajax_update_shipping_method'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, WC_AJAX::update_shipping_method, WC_AJAX::get_cart_totals, woocommerce_cart_totals, wc_get_template, include('/plugins/woocommerce/templates/cart/cart-totals.php'), wc_cart_totals_coupon_html, apply_filters('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html'), WP_Hook->apply_filters, my_coupon_percentage_cart, WC_Legacy_Coupon->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
```

Any idea what could be wrong with my code?

Comment: The error messages already indicate it: _discount_type and coupon_amount was called incorrectly_. So to solve this you have to call them correctly. This can be done by replacing `$coupon->discount_type` with `$coupon->get_discount_type()` and `$coupon->coupon_amount` with `$coupon->get_amount()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the object properties durectly, instead use the methods like this

```
// Add Coupon Percentage to Cart

function my_coupon_percentage_cart($value, $coupon)
{
    if($coupon->get_discount_type() == 'percent' && !empty($coupon->get_amount()))
    {
        $amt = "<br><br><p><em><strong>{$coupon->get_amount()}% OFF</strong></em></p>";   
    }

    return $value.$amt;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_totals_coupon_html','my_coupon_percentage_cart',10,2);
```

Comment: Thank for the solution. Is there a way to display it also on the checkout page?

Comment: It should work on checkout page as well

Comment: Not exactly. I had to change filter to woocommerce_checkout_totals_coupon_html and then it worked